# python multiprocessing sharing file in memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, mmap

I'm implementing a multiprocessing program in python, and for each of the subprocess, they all need to read part of a file.

Since reading the file from the disk is expensive, I want to read it only once and put in shared memory.

**1. If I use mmap, it can work with fork, but I can't find a way to share the mmaped file between Processes in the multiprocessing module.**

**2. If I read in the file into a str, and store the string in sharedctypes.RawArray('c', str), an error can occur if the there is a \0 in the str, the RawArray generated is a truncate of the file.**

Any idea?

Comment: you can use `numpy.memmap` to open the file if it is an array in mode `'r+'`, with each process working on a different region of the array

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the multiprocessing Managers? Make the mmped file an attribute of the NameSpace Object returned by the `Namespace()` function and pass a reference of this to each of the processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

mgr = Manager()
ns = mgr.Namespace()
ns.df = my_dataframe

# now just give your processes access to ns, i.e. most simply
# p = Process(target=worker, args=(ns, work_unit))
```

(my answer is basically copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between))