# More compound wise object sharing in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Can I share compound objects, like e.g. pandas dataframe between parallel processes in python multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the **multiprocessing.Manager**, like it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between).
There's also PySpark, which has its [own dataframe structure](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html) with inherent parallelization, and it can be converted into pandas and vice versa.