# share python object between multiprocess in python3

Tags: multithreading, performance, python-3.x, communication

Here I create a producer-customer program,the parent process(producer) create many child process(consumer)，then parent process read file and pass data to child process.

but , here comes a performance problem,pass message between process cost too much time （I think）.

for an example ,a **200MB** original data ,parent process read and pretreat will cost less then **8** seconds , than just pass data to child process by multiprocess.**pipe** will cost another **8** seconds , and child processes do the remain work just cost another **3 ~ 4** seconds.

so ,a complete work flow cost less than 18 seconds ,and more than 40% time  cost on communication between process , it is much bigger than I used think about ,and I tried multiprocess.**Queue** and **Manager** ,they are **worse**.

I works with windows7 / Python3.4.
I had google for several days , and POSH maybe a good solution , but it can't build with python3.4

there I have 3 ways:

**1.is there any way can share python object direct between process in Python3.4 ? as POSH**

or

**2.is it possable pass the "pointer" of an object to child process and child process can recovery the "pointer" to python object?**

or

**3.multiprocess.Array may be a valid solution , but if I want share complex data structure, such as list, how it works? should I make a new class base on it and provide interfaces as list?**

**Edit1:**
I tried the 3rd way,but it works worse.
I defined those value:

```
p_pos = multiprocessing.Value('i') #producer write position  
c_pos = multiprocessing.Value('i') #customer read position  
databuff = multiprocess.Array('c',buff_len) # shared buffer
```

and two function:

```
send_data(msg)  
get_data()
```

in **send_data** function(parent process),it copies msg to databuff , and send the start and end position (two integer)to child process via pipe.
than in **get_data** function (child process) ,it received the two position and copy the msg from databuff.

in final,it cost twice than just use pipe @_@

**Edit 2:**
Yes , I tried Cython ,and the result looks good.
I just changed my python script's suffix to .pyx and compile it ,and the program speed up for 15%.
No doubt , I met the " Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" and " The system cannot find the file specified" error , and I cost whole day for solved the first one , and blocked by the second one.
Finally , I found **[Cyther](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cyther/0.7.0)** , and all troubles gone ^_^.

Comment: all of I want is a queue that parent put message in to and child process get message out from ,and with out too much move operation such as Pipe or Queue in multiprocess module

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was at your place five month ago. I looked around few times but my conclusion is multiprocessing with Python has exactly the problem you describe :

- Pipes and Queue are good but not for big objects from my experience
- Manager() proxies objects are slow except arrays and those one are limited. if you want to share a complex data structure use a Namespace like it is done here : [multiprocessing in python - sharing large object (e.g. pandas dataframe) between multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between)
- Manager() has a shared list you are looking for : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html
- There are no pointers or real memory management in Python, so you can't share selected memory cells

I solved this kind of problem by learning C++, but it's probably not what you want to read...

Comment: Thanks . So this bottleneck is cased by python itself.And you said you "solved this kind of problem by learning C++" , it means that you rewrite all program with C++ ?  or just the communication between process?

Comment: Usually I only rewrite what needs to be, so as you said the communication between process, and I get back my functions using boost.python or Cython. It is hard, but only the first time ;)

Comment: @ Jean-Baptiste F. Thanks a lot , I will try the Cython.

Comment: You are welcome, please tag the question as answered if you think it's the case!

Answer (score 0):

To pass data (especially big numpy arrays) to a child process, I think [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html) can be very efficient since I can work directly on buffer-like objects.

An example of using mpi4py to spawn processes and communicate (using also trio, but it is another story) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178108/1779806).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's a very old question, and the office in where I asked this question had been closed yet...but still thanks. I accessed the official page of mpi4py, it looks a bit like "fork", I will try it and measure the performance, hope it could work as good as shared memory.