# Sharing a large object across python-based microservices

Tags: python, parallel-processing, microservices

Imagine I have multiple python processes running from independent scripts on a single machine. They all need read-only access to a monolithic data object, say a `pandas.DataFrame`. Assume that the object is so large that only one copy will fit into memory. I would like to implement something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between) but with more of a local server architecture without spawning all my workers from a single head process via `multiprocessing`. If the object was fully immutable I would use [Plasma](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html), but unfortunately the server may have to change the contents from time to time.

Can you recommend a good python package or some example code to do that?