# Assigning a pandas dataframe to multiprocessing SharedMemory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shared-memory

Is there a straightforward way to assign a pandas dataframe to a multiprocessing SharedMemory buffer? Converting the dataframe to numpy arrays first or pickling it is not an option. Also, the dataframe is in the order of gigabytes.

Comment: This question is a replication of [multiprocessing in python - sharing large object (e.g. pandas dataframe) between multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between)