# Share pandas dataframe among workers using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a problem sharing a pandas dataframe among workers using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Each worker need to read a of CSV files. I would like to load them in memory only once for all workers and I need to update the dataframe when new files are added. Here a sandbox I have been trying to get to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os

def process(par):
    new_data = pd.DataFrame([[par[0], int(os.getpid())]], columns=['A', 'B'])
    par[1].df = pd.concat((par[1].df, new_data), ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:

        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        shared = manager.Namespace()
        shared.df =  pd.DataFrame()

        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as exe:        

            nx = range(0, 100)
            ny = [shared]*len(nx)
            par = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(nx, ny)]
            exe.map(process, par)
```

In this example `process` add a new line to the shared dataframe every time it is called. I pass two variables to `process` because in my real life example I need to do so.

The problem: I end up with `shared.df` having between 65 and 80 rows instead of 100 (loop of 100 iteration). The number of rows changes at every run. Is that because some worker find the dataframe "busy"? Any idea how can I solve this? Is this the right method at all?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Two more attempts:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import os
import time

# Define a worker function
def worker_function(name):
    existing_shm = SharedMemory(name=name)
    c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    c +=1
    existing_shm.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8])
    shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes)
    b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    b[:] = a[:]

    # Create a ProcessPoolExecutor and use map to distribute the work
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as exe:        
        exe.map(worker_function, [shm.name]*100)

    # Check result
    print(b)

    # Clean up the shared memory
    shm.unlink()
```

But only some elements of the numpy array are modified: `b=[101, 1, 102, 3, 105, 8]`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
import os

# Define a worker function
def worker_function(var):
    var[0] = var[0] + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:

        init = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        sl = smm.ShareableList(init)   
        print(sl)

        # Create a ProcessPoolExecutor and use map to distribute the work
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as exe:        
            exe.map(worker_function, [sl]*1000 )

        print(sl)
```

In this case I couldn't find a way to share something that is NOT a list which is inconvenient. And I still have one iteration missing: `sl = [999,1,2,3,4,5,6]` and not 1000 in sl[0].

Comment: " the shared dataframe " it's not shared.. processes don't share memory, they each get their own separate copy. Data must be explicitly passed to and from processes. There is no inherent sharing unless you use `multiprocessing.shared_memory` or some other memory mapped file.

Comment: But then why shared.df has around 70 rows at the end? The loop is `range(100)` and it runs on 16 cores. Can you provide an example with `multiprocessing.shared_memory`. I should find the website where I got inspired...

Comment: I think this is where part of my solution was taken (I remember another website I cannot find anymore): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between

Comment: my bad... I overlooked the usage of the `manager` in your first post. The methods of the proxy object are executed in the manager process in threads, so you are likely getting a race condition in reading `shared.df` then concatenating and replacing `shared.df` as it is executed in parallel threads. you can prove this by limiting the pool to 1 process where there will be no parallel requests to the proxy.

Comment: And there is no way to tell processes to wait if the dataframe is "busy"? Do you have an explanation why shared_memory may behave the way it does in my new examples?