Multiprocessing with batching
I'd love to do multiprocessing to speed up the program. My input file contains 30 million rows. I'd love to run 10 processes in parallel. But my file is very large (contains 30 million rows). I'm worried that the running memory will explode. Does anyone know what should I do? Below is the code that performs in single process. Thanks in advance.
batch_size = 1000 
header_written = False
output_file = "final_patent_sample.csv"
for i in tqdm(range(0, df2_csv.shape[0], batch_size)):
   batch = df2_csv.iloc[i:i + batch_size].to_dict(orient='records')
   results = match_and_merge(batch)
   batch_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=matched_df.columns)
   batch_df.to_csv(output_file, mode='a', index=False, header=not header_written)
   header_written = True 


"I want one processing to deal with one batch size" what exactly do you mean? Have you tried anything at all? Questions of the form "please solve this open problem for me" are not suitable for StackOverflow - but we can help you fix a specific approach or solve whatever it is you're stuck on.

@Grismar Sorry!! I'm not making it clear. I'd love to run 10 processes in parallel. But as the file is too large, I'm worried that the running memory will explode for each process. Should I then use batching? I apologize.

It's going to be very tricky to get everything you have going on here working in a multiprocessing environment. Having a progress bar with tqdm, writing out to a file, and processing batches of values at once are all a bit tricky. Would an answer that leaves out some of those pieces be acceptable? Also, which parts are slowest? If we parallelize match_and_merge, but writing out to a CSV is the slower step, we won't get anywhere useful.

If each batch is independent, you could write a preprocessing program that splits the original csv into many files, one per batch. Then, you could have a process pool work on them individually. Finally, a script could take the individual outputs and make the output csv. This avoids the 30 million records in memory at the same time.

Use a Manager to share a single dataframe between processes and just give each process some indices - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22487898/6557588 as a pointer

Are you saying that df2_csv is a dataframe comprised of all 30 million rows? Also, if you're going to have multiple processes appending to the same file you will need to introduce some form of locking to defend against potential interlacing

@Blckknght Thanks for your comment. match_and_merge is the slowest. writing to CSV I think is not slow.

@SIGHUP Thanks for your comment. Yes, df2_csv is the dataframe comprised of all 30 million rows.

@tdelaney Thank you very much for your suggestion!

If match_and_merge is substantially slower than all the data handling bits of your code, then I think it's possible to parallelize just that step, while keeping the rest of the code in the main process. This may be a bit slower than parallelizing the batching stuff too, but it makes some of the problem simpler to implement.
batch_size = 1000 
header_written = False
output_file = "final_patent_sample.csv"
with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
    batch_generator = (df2_csv.iloc[i:i + batch_size].to_dict(orient='records')
                       for i in range(0, df2_csv.shape[0], batch_size))
    for results in pool.imap(match_and_merge, batch_generator):
        batch_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=matched_df.columns)
        batch_df.to_csv(output_file, mode='a', index=False, header=not header_written)
        header_written = True 

This may not work perfectly as written, as it copies all the data between processes, and that may be too slow for you to see benefits from parallelization. It's probably possible to share your big dataframe between processes using some kind of shared memory scheme, but I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to give advice on exactly how to do it. The results are also being copied back to the main process to be written out serially, which may be slower than figuring out some kind of distributed writing, with a locking to maintain file consistency. I've also cut the progress bar from tqdm, as I don't have the library installed to test with. It can probably be wrapped around the pool.imap(...) call, but I'm not entirely sure that will work, so I left it out.

This is a refinement to the answer posted by Blckknght:
The multiprocessing.pool.imap method will iterate whatever iterable is passed to it filling up the pool's input task queue much faster than the pool processes can process the task. And since the results returned need to be written out, which is even slower than the rate tasks can be processed, then the pool's output "queue" will also fill up. The result is that you would be using a lot of memory. The solution is to "throttle" the rate that the iterable can be iterated and we do this with a Semaphore initialized to the maximum number of tasks that can be being processed or waiting to be processed on the input task queue:
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
from threading import Semaphore

...

def main():
    n_rows = df2_csv.shape[0]  # Number of rows in dataframe
    batch_size = 1000
    pool_size = 10
    # If writing the CSV file is much slower than the processing
    # of each batch, then probably not much is to be gained by
    # having max_tasks larger than the pool size and it would use
    # more memory.
    max_tasks = pool_size

    task_semaphore = Semaphore(max_tasks)

    def gen_tasks():
        # Throttle generation of batches to keep
        # memory utilization down
        for i in range(0, n_rows, batch_size):
            task_semaphore.acquire()
            yield df2_csv.iloc[i:i + batch_size].to_dict(orient='records')

    header_written = False
    output_file = "final_patent_sample.csv"
    with multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        for results in pool.imap(match_and_merge, gen_tasks()):
            batch_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=matched_df.columns)
            batch_df.to_csv(output_file, mode='a', index=False, header=not header_written)
            header_written = True
            # Allow another task to be submited:
            task_semaphore.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

gen_tasks can generate max_tasks tasks for the imap method before it will block on acquiring the semaphore. But every time a result is returned back to the main process and appended to the CSV file, the semaphore will be "released" allowing gen_tasks to generate a new task. This will keep both the input and output task queues limited each to max_task batches. You should adjust the batch size for a balance between performance (larger batch size) and memory utilization(smaller batch size).
